# GAE Python how can I pass and retrieve a parameter to a request handler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parameter-passing

--- Rewrote question to make it clearer and included code ---

I'm building my first GAE python app, and need to figure out how to pass parameters among the different modules of my system in such a way that the different request handlers can pick these parameters up.

I have a main page for my app, it is a page with buttons the user can click on to jump to the different system blocks (Products, Recipes, Orders..). The user logs in on the main page, and this login should be pervasive through all blocks of the system.

The href's on the main page now look like:

```
<a href="products">Products
<a href="recipes">Recipes
<a href="orders">Orders
```

Not all users have access to all blocks, I keep a list in the datastore with access rights.

Now take the Products page: the user should only be allowed acces to this page if his/her login in the datastore indicates enough access rights to that page.

The user clicks on the product link (or button) in the main page, and lands on the "../products" page which is in the products.py file.

In products.py I offer the user (again) to select from different options. By default the user gets directed to the first handler, and sees a new list of options.

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/products', ProductsPage),
    ('/products-save', SaveProduct),
    ('/products-find', FindProduct),
    ('/products-delete', DeleteProduct),    
    ('/products-search', SearchProducts),
], debug = True)
```

Suppose the user now chooses to create or save a product. He will be directed to the ../products-save page, which is handled by SaveProduct.

This request handler starts with:

```
class SaveProduct(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # if user_id is authorized to create / modify products:
        #     code ...
        # else display nice message "not enough rights"
```

I got the user_id on the main page, and need to transport it through all the intermediate steps so it arrives at the final function (SaveProduct in this example) on anther .py file in order for it to validate if the user has enough rights.

My question is: how do I do this?

I have checked the webapp2 docs for the config option and about get, but didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: this question is very unclear to me. are you talking about query strings? do you have code you could show?

Comment: Hi @aschmid00, thanks for the reply. I added code to the question and explained what I had done so far. Maybe the question is clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a request coming from a web page that the user fills out and submits then the getting started tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) has some examples of how to do this. Specifically, the parameters from an HTML form will be part of the [request](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html) object that your request handler code receives and you just grab them out by name in your handler code. The links assume that you're using the webapp2 framework but the process is the same for other frameworks.

Comment: Hi gcobb, thanks but maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I had already adapted the code in the tutorial to pass the contents of the search box in the form to a request handler: the search string is  passed without problems. My real question is how do I pass a parameter not from the form but from code? e.g. to allow/deny users access to certain parts of the system I need to pass the user_id or his authorization level to the different modules. BTW, I'm validating the user against a list in the datastore where I can check which modules the user can access and if its r/o or r/w.

Comment: A hidden input field would allow you to pass along form data that is not generally visible to the user, but this is a risky way to do auth since a savvy user can easily change the value sent to the server. It's probably safer to send some user identification to the server and have the server side check what access the user has.